# JButton does not open JDialog

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, actionlistener, jdialog

I am building a simple program. I have a class that extends from JDialog and class that extends from JFrame and is GUI of the application. I implemented ActionListener which should open the dialog after clicking on the JButton. Nothing happens though and I can't figure out why.

**GUI**

```
    package nemocnice_sam;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.HeadlessException;
import java.awt.ScrollPane;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;

public class App extends JFrame {

    JTable tbl = new JTable();
    JButton pridejPacienta = new JButton("Přidej pacienta");
    JButton smazPacienta = new JButton("Smaž pacienta");
    JButton export = new JButton("Export");
    JButton konec = new JButton("Konec");
    JPanel panel = new JPanel();

    PacientDialog novyPacient;

    ActionListener al = new ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            if(e.getSource() == pridejPacienta){
                novyPacient = new PacientDialog();
                novyPacient.setModal(true);
                novyPacient.setVisible(true);

            }

        }
    };

    SeznamPacientu pacienti = new SeznamPacientu();
    ModelPacientu model = new ModelPacientu(pacienti);





    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new App();

    }



    public App() {
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        panel.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT));
        panel.add(pridejPacienta);
        panel.add(smazPacienta);
        panel.add(export);
        panel.add(konec);

        add(panel,BorderLayout.NORTH);
        tbl.setModel(model);
        add(new JScrollPane(tbl), BorderLayout.CENTER);
        setVisible(true);

        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        pack();
    }





}
```

**DIALOG CLASS**

```
    package nemocnice_sam;

import java.awt.GridLayout;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JDialog;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class PacientDialog extends JDialog {

    JTextField jmeno = new JTextField();
    JTextField prijmeni = new JTextField();
    JTextField rc = new JTextField();
    JTextField cp = new JTextField();
    JButton ok = new JButton("OK");

    public PacientDialog(){
        setLayout(new GridLayout(5,2));
        add(new JLabel("Jméno:"));
        add(jmeno);
        add(new JLabel("Příjmení:"));
        add(prijmeni);
        add(new JLabel("RČ:"));
        add(rc);
        add(new JLabel("ČP:"));
        add(cp);
        pack();
    }

}
```

Comment: Do you ever bind the `actionListener` you create to a button or another component using for example `pridejPacienta.addActionListener(...)` ?

Comment: You have your answer but here is a simple checklist **1** Is my action is running ? **2**Is my action is bind to the button **3** Is it the correct button

Comment: Just for the record: when creating an [mcve] ... consider using **all english** vocabulary. The primary language is English here, and any input that comes in a different language simply decreases your chances of helpful answers. Not in this case though.

Comment: [How to write ActionListeners](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/actionlistener.html) and [How to use buttons](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/button.html)

Answer (score 6):

You need to define the actionListener in button.

```
konec.addActionListener(al);
```

Comment: I am not trying to use button "konec". I need it to open when i click on pridejPacienta @josivan

Comment: `pridejPacienta.addActionListener(al)`. You need to understand and use the answer based on your context. josivan could have simply said `mybutton.addActionListener(myActionListener)`. You should understand what to do from this.

Comment: @TomášNosek, then add listener in the pridejPacienta button. `pridejPacienta,addActionListener(al);`

Answer (score 5):

Defining an ActionListener alone is not sufficient.

In order to do its job, that listener must be **registered** with some component that actually sends Events to that Listener.

So you have it to add to the corresponding button for example, like:

```
pridejPacienta.addActionListener(al);
```

Besides: when you do that, you do **not** need that `if (source ==` check within your action listener. You see, when **each** button has a **distinct** listener, then there will not be **different** sources.

You only need such kinds of checks when you want to attach the **same** ActionListener to multiple buttons!